# Save a bitmap to file

Tags: java, android, android-image

I want to open one image from my assets folder, resize it and resave the image. I use this code:

```
private void resizeImage(float ratio) {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = assetManager.open("bear.png");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return;
    }
    Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

    int width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
    int height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();

    float scaleWidth = ((float) width) / ratio;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) height) / ratio;

    Matrix aMatrix = new Matrix();
    aMatrix.setSkew(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    bitmapOrg = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, bitmapOrg.getWidth(),
            bitmapOrg.getHeight(), aMatrix, false);

}
```

But when I start application it crash. This is stack trace:

```
12-09 02:36:33.750: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
12-09 02:36:33.750: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
12-09 02:36:33.750: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1939):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:444)
```

Does someone know why crash?

Comment: Just a quick thought... what happens if you replace the last line with this: final Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, bitmapOrg.getWidth(), bitmapOrg.getHeight(), aMatrix, false);

Comment: There still the same stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assets folder is located inside the APK, and thus is not a true folder in the File System.
I don't think you can save anything there.